# Save the result in JSON file when using post request in AJAX and Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax

Now I am writing an javascript to track the system configuration of users e.g screen resolution statistic. I first wrote the AJAX file to collection in object form and use node.js to take the request and finally write the input into the json file in server side.

My AJAX code is as follows:

```
  try{

  window.onload = function(url, callback, data, x) {
  var sWidth = screen.width;
  var sHeight = screen.height;
  var sColor = screen.colorDepth;
  var sPlatform = window.navigator.platform;
  var sLanguage = navigator.language;
  var sTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

  var info = {
    width: sWidth,
    height: sHeight,
    color: sColor,
    platform: sPlatform,
    language: sLanguage,
    timezone: sTimeZone
  };

    //var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var http = new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');

    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(http.response));
      }
    };

    http.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/ReturnFingerprint.json", true);
    http.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    http.setRequestHeader("Content", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    http.send(info);
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

And the following Node.js code to take over the AJAX request

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app= express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.options('/Fingerprint', cors()) ;

app.post('/Fingerprint', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('ReturnFingerprint.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err)
    } else {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      json = JSON.stringify(data);
      fs.writeFile('ReturnFingerprint.json', json, 'utf8', function writeFilecallback (err, data) {
        res.json(json)});
      });
    }
  }
  res.json(json);
});
```

When I checked the json file, there is nth updated.

And when I inspected the network element in google chrome, it returns that the ReturnFingerprint.json is pending and no more error message or detail is provided.

What is the error of the code?Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Express that you're done with handling of the request eg. by `res.send('hello')` or `res.json(jsonObject)`. You should call it in the writeFile callback.

Comment: Thanks! Do u mean in the last command it should be: fs.writeFile('ReturnFingerprint.json', json, 'utf8', function writeFilecallback (err, data) {
        res.json(json)}); ?

Comment: Yes. And if some error happens you should call `next(error)` (next is 3rd parameter of the request handler `function(req, res, next)`)

If you won't finish the request either by `request.send` or `next` the server won't finish the request. Look at the Express guides, there are the topics well explained https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Hi, I edited the code, but unfortunately the error is still the same...which is the JSON is still pending and did not return the result.....Did I edit sth wrong? @Jan Steuer

Comment: You should call `res.json` only once for every request but you call it multiple times in your case - first at the end of the main function and then in the callback. But I don't see a reason why the request isn't finished.

Try starting with a simple route definition and then adding the other functions: `app.post('/Fingerprint', urlencodedParser, (req, res, next) => res.send(req.body))`